# JSP Delete Row from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, dao

I generated a list of people in my JSP using MySQL and the problem is how I should delete them. This is my code:

JSP:

```
                        <% ApplicantDAO applicantDAO = new ApplicantDAO();%>
                <% for (int i = 0; i < applicantDAO.viewApplicant().size(); i++) {%>

                <div class="column">
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">


                        <div class="list-group">


                            <a  class="list-group-item active">
                                <img src = "th_1x1.jpg" class = "img-responsive" alt = "Responsive Image" width = "100%" height ="100">
                                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" id="guardName<%=+i%>" id="guardName<%=+i%>"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantFirstName() + " "%>
                                    <%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantLastName()%></h4>                 
                            </a>
                            <a  class="list-group-item">
                                <p class="list-group-item-text" id="applyingFor<%=+i%>" id="applyingFor<%=+i%>"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplyingFor()%></p>
                            </a>
                            <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" href="#moreDetails<%=+i%>">
                                <button  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="moreDetails">More Details</button>                                   
                            </a>
                            <a  class="list-group-item">
                                <form action="deleteApplicant" action="post">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default delete" aria-label="Left Align" id="accept<%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantID()%>">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                                <form>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default delete" aria-label="Left Align" id="reject<%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantID()%>">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                            </a>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="moreDetails<%=+i%>">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                            <h3 class="modal-title">Applicant Information</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <h2 class="text-center"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantLastName() + ", "%><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantFirstName()%></h2>
                                            <h4 class="text-center" id="id"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantID()%></h4>
```

The following code generates the people using the for loop I made. However, my problem is getting the ID of what I am going to delete. This is my code of the servlet:

```
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        try {
            Applicant deletedApplicant = new Applicant();
            String value = request.getParameter("ID");
            int id = Integer.parseInt(value);
            ApplicantDAO applicantDAO = new ApplicantDAO();

            boolean successful = applicantDAO.rejectApplicant(deletedApplicant.getApplicantID());

             if (successful){
            ServletContext context= getServletContext();
            RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("/HiringPage.jsp");
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("deletedApplicant", deletedApplicant);
            rd.forward(request, response);
            System.out.println("successful");
        }else{
            ServletContext context= getServletContext();
            RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("/Dashboard.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

And lastly, this is my code of the controller:

```
    public boolean rejectApplicant(int applicantID) {
    try {
        DBConnectionFactory myFactory = DBConnectionFactory.getInstance();
        Connection conn = myFactory.getConnection();

        String query = "delete from applicant where applicantID = ?";

        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setInt(1, applicantID);

        int rows = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();
        pstmt.close();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ApplicantDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can you please guide me on how to do things? Thank you so much!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Nothing. It doesnt show any error at all

Comment: String query = "delete from applicant where applicantID = ?"; where is setInt?

Comment: Please check edited code

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in this part of code

```
     <form action="deleteApplicant" action="post">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default delete" aria-label="Left Align" id="accept<%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantID()%>">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </button>
    </form>
    <form>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default delete" aria-label="Left Align" id="reject<%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantID()%>">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 </button>
 </form>
```

I don't understand why did you put 2 forms but as you put your servlet in the first I suggest that you add a hidden input in the form where you put the ID

```
 <form action="deleteApplicant" action="post">
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantID()%>"/>

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default delete" aria-label="Left Align" id="accept<%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantID()%>">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
        </form>
```

you can get this ID value using servlet with

```
String value = request.getParameter("ID");
```

you should know that the second form that you put

```
<form>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default delete" aria-label="Left Align" id="reject<%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantID()%>">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 </button>
 </form>
```

doesn't pass any parameter to servlet

so change it to

```
<form action="deleteApplicant" action="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantID()%>"/>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default delete" aria-label="Left Align" id="reject<%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantID()%>">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     </button>
     </form>
```

#### After your edit :

why did you pass

```
boolean successful = applicantDAO.rejectApplicant(deletedApplicant.getApplicantID());
```

simply pass

```
 boolean successful = applicantDAO.rejectApplicant(id);
```

Comment: I put two forms because the first one is for accepting and the other for deleting. And how do you do the hidden input? THank you

Comment: so you should put your servlet in second form and the hidden input I Add it to your code

Comment: yes you put delete servlet in the accepting part and that's your first problem

Comment: It is still the same. I have changed it before you said that and it really shows no error messages

Comment: your second problem that you put an input type="button" you should change it to type="submit" . My answer is edited

Comment: It works now, but the servlet is not working. I can see it when I click the button this is being shown: http://localhost:8080/Safeguard/deleteApplicant?ID=6 but it does not remove the entry from the DB. It just refreshes the page

Comment: now we are certain that there is no problem in jsp code so you must check the code of your servlet (connection with DB ,...)

Comment: It is already working. Thank youso much for your time sir! :)

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer the button in the left

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post sco